# Essential checks for Face verification Input

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition

I am working on "Face Verification" algorithm with Mobile phone images.
I am planning to capture the query/test images only when they meet some standard checks as below.

1. 2d Frontal - How to ensure the image is 2D frontal or not?
2. How to check the user is in good/recommended lighting conditions
3. What is the best recommended distance between the eyes should be? And how to calculate the distance between the eyes in a face?

Is there any thing else? and how to do points 1, 2, 3 in opencv?

Comment: I hope your'e not trying to implement face recognition by using the distance between the eyes... That would not work.

Comment: @GilLevi I am not trying to do face recognition using distance between eye. I am just trying to reject the input image too the face recognition algorithm if the eye distance is below some threshold. As you know a good image to the face recognition algorithms will give good accuracy.

Comment: Do you want to do this because you think your face recognition algorithm is too slow and you want to 'speed it up' by neglecting non-face images, or is it an additional measure to reduce false-positives?

Comment: @Random-I-Am yes you can say as to reduce the false-positives. As you might know, good images to face recognition algorithms will always gives good results.

Comment: @user2881263 I'm not sure if I entirely understand you last sentence. However, since I don't know how familiar you are with this: Did you consider just pre-processing the data using the [Violia-Jones](https://lissyx.dyndns.org/redmine/projects/usbdriver/repository/revisions/136/raw/trunk/rapport_rf/refs/TR2003-96.pdf) face-detection algorithm for a start?